# Extract the matching number from the list of elements

Tags: python, regex

I have the List of elements mixed with numbers, letters and special characters:

```
string = ['1 B, 14/A - P,1C,2A,21 C - A',    
          '3P,21B,2-A,1A',
          '3C,2-W,ABC 200',
          '3 Z,ABC 100 - BB',
          'ABC 300,ABC 200',
          'ABC 200,ABC 100',
          '1c/A,2 - z']
```

I want to extract the elements which are matching the condition.

Condition: Elements in the list should be `starting with the Matching number` or
starting with `ABC (Matching number)`

Required output:

```
starting_with_one = ['1 B, 14/A - P,1C,2A,21 C - A', # ---> Here `1 B ,14/A - P,1C` are contains the number 1  
                     '3P,21B,2-A,1A',                # ---> Here `1A` Contains the number 1   
                     '3 Z,ABC 100 - BB',             # ---> Here `ABC 100 - BB` Contains the number 1  
                     'ABC 200,ABC 100',              # ---> Here `ABC 100` Contains the number 1
                     '1c/A,2 - z']                   # ---> Here `1c/A' contains 1

starting_with_two = ['1 B, 14/A - P,1C,2A,21 C - A',
                     '3P,21B,2-A,1A',
                     '3C,2-W,ABC 200',
                     'ABC 300,ABC 200',
                     'ABC 200,ABC 100',
                     '1c/A,2 - z']
```

What I tried :

Searching to the number `1`:

```
for i in string:
    print(re.search(r"(^|[^\d])(1)", i))

<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(10, 12), match=',1'>
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 9), match=' 1'>
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(11, 13), match=' 1'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: What are your requirements? The conditions you describe seem overlapping and unclear. What is the difference between `starting_with_one` and `starting_with_two`?

Comment: what is a `Matching Number`? please include expected output in the post.

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/xJ2dyf, `if re.search(r'(?:^|,)(ABC\s+)?1', s):
        print(s)`. The pattern might also be `r'\b(ABC\s+)?1'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 2nd one working perfectly. Thank you

Comment: If you think my answer is helpful, please also consider upvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'\b(?:ABC\s+)?1'
```

to identify the strings you want to keep. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dvktQR/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:ABC\s+)?` - an optional substring: `ABC` and then 1+ whitespaces
- `1` - `1` char.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tid28S):

```
import re
strs = ['1 B, 14/A - P,1C,2A,21 C - A','3P,21B,2-A,1A','3C,2-W,ABC 200','3 Z,ABC 100 - BB','ABC 300,ABC 200','ABC 200,ABC 100','1c/A,2 - z']
for s in strs:
    if re.search(r'\b(?:ABC\s+)?1', s):
        print(s)
```

Output:

```
1 B, 14/A - P,1C,2A,21 C - A
3P,21B,2-A,1A
3 Z,ABC 100 - BB
ABC 200,ABC 100
1c/A,2 - z
```

Comment: @ wiktor its consider the following pattern also asd-1,7-1

Comment: it should  not be taken

Comment: Then use `(?<![^\s,])(?:ABC\s+)?1`, see https://regex101.com/r/dvktQR/2